# Why is Laravel 8 sanctum tokenCan not working?

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-sanctum

I've added an key in the database with abilities "user:addkeys".

[image]

In my `routes/api.php` I've changed the route to create new keys into this:

```php
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->post('/tokens/create', function (Request $request) {
    $user = User::find($request->user_id);
    $retval = [];

    if ($user->tokenCan('user:addkeys')) {
        $capabilities = explode(',',$request->capabilities);
        $token = $user->createToken($request->token_name, $capabilities);
        return ['token' => $token->plainTextToken];
    }
    return $retval;
});
```

When I run the url via Postman with the token that exists in the database im able to pass the auth:sanctum but the tokenCan keeps returning false.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Instead of `$user = User::find($request->user_id)` I now use `$user = $request->user()`

I think the tokenCan() only works on a request.